# Python's 'cmd' listing all command options, regardless of nested level

Tags: python

I'm new to python, python's 'cmd' command-line parser/interpreter, and to stackOverflow as question-asker, well. A real newbie. Sorry.

My question: I've got a nested looping cli using the above that works, well, pretty okay considering the total newness.

When I type 'help' I get an appropriate list of possible commands, based on the code so far. When I enter a command that drops me to a nested level, and then type 'help', I get the same list of possible commands. It appears that they're commands across the whole python app.

What I'm looking for is a nested level, context sensitive list of commands available at that level. So, I would expect that when I'm down a level, I would only see the commands available at that level? Yeah?

I could show code, but I'm certain that it would just complicate things, and the concept is pretty straight forward, I think.

If python's 'cmd' is not the way to go, that's okay. I only have an afternoon's worth of time into this effort, but don't want to go further until I sort this out.

Thanks to all for a great site and great people using it.

Jeff

Comment: What version of are you using - as 'help' on my interactive interpreter doesn't do what you are describing.

Comment: Are you speaking about `cmd` module? Isn't it? In that case you must implement `help_*` to show the subcommand help according to the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.cmdloop

Comment: Hi Tony and Michele, thanks both.. I'm using python 2.7 and yes, I'm referring to the cmd module. Michele, if I understand your reply correctly, I'm currently seeing all possible do_* commands listed. What I'm trying to understand is how to only see the commands for the level of nesting. I am about to switch back into this part of the project and appreciate the help from you both! I'm going to re-review the cmd help file - thanks !!